# Concerning sshd login attemps from unknown IP

Tags: linux, ssh, security, openssh, google-cloud-platform

I am running a Google Cloud Rocky Linux instance

For some operations, SFTP is required

I have found some concerning sshd login attemps from an unknown IP, limited logs below

```
Mar 09 15:29:16 server-name sshd[1533432]: Invalid user user from 64.227.164.1 port 42140
Mar 09 15:29:16 server-name sshd[1533424]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 64.227.164.1 port 42120 [preauth]
Mar 09 15:29:16 server-name sshd[1533423]: Connection closed by invalid user admin 64.227.164.1 port 42092 [preauth]
Mar 09 15:29:16 server-name sshd[1533427]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 64.227.164.1 port 42128 [preauth]
Mar 09 15:29:16 server-name sshd[1533425]: Connection closed by invalid user guest 64.227.164.1 port 41830 [preauth]
Mar 09 15:29:16 server-name sshd[1533429]: Connection closed by invalid user ali 64.227.164.1 port 42074 [preauth]
Mar 09 15:29:16 server-name sshd[1533432]: Connection closed by invalid user user 64.227.164.1 port 42140 [preauth]
```

After doing some research, I found this for the **64.227.164.1** IP

[image: Ip adress lookup info]

I am wondering if there is anything I could do to prevent these connections, (such as flagging & blocking many attemps from same IP within a small timespan) as I would not like a breach in the system

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a public IP then no, you can't prevent these. Someone's always knocking on the doors - you can see these even in home router logs.

This is just bruteforcing using a word list. So first thing to keep them out is disabling SSH access for root. Or as this is a cloud system, disable all root access and `sudo` when needed.

Secondly, make sure there aren't default usernames like admin, guest or user. Also I'd keep my actual user accounts a bit more imaginative than john or mary.

Thirdly ensure your firewall's properly configured and up-to-date. Don't have ports open you don't absolutely need. In the end that's its job, keeping these knockers out.

You can also add another layer of security like SSHGuard Colin suggests. About 95% of these knock-knocks I've ever analyzed have originated from web hosting service IP ranges and the attempts from a single address don't usually last very long.

Answer (score 1):

Something like https://www.sshguard.net/ would work - it watches your SSH logs and blocks IPs that are trying to bruteforce your logins.